# Properties of limits on functions

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to a}{\ln{f(x)}}=\ln(\lim_{x\to a}f(x))$$

or

$$\lim_{x\to a}{e^{f(x)}}=e^{(\lim_{x\to a}x)}$$

I always found out those properties when proving limits for the base definition of the number $e$.  Does this hold true for other types of functions, such as trigonometric functions?  Also how does one make a rigourous proof for the above properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If function $g$ is continuous at $a$, then
$$
\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=g(\lim_{x\to a}x)
$$
$\ln$, $\exp$, $\sin$, $\cos$, and so on are continuous on their domains.